# NO Html Data is mailed Using Php Mailer Library

Tags: php, email

what I Need:

- when user click on button mail with html content should recipent recived.

  My problem:

  - No Html Content is Send in mail.

here is my code mail.php

```
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $message = '
<html>
 <head>
<title>ES Html Report</title>
 </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Project Name</th>
  <th>TODo</th>
  <th>Priority</th>
  <th>Due on</th>
  <th>Assignee</th>
  <th>Created</th>
  <th>Updated</th>
  <th>Completed</th>
  <th>Assignee Status</th>
 <th>Status</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>aaaa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sally</td
</tr>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>ankit</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1-09-89</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1-08-77</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>177th</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ok</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>gg</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1710th</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSendmail();
 $mail->setFrom('af15@gmail.com', 'First Last');
//$mail->addReplyTo('af@ankrus.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('aef@anus.com', 'John Doe');
 $mail->Subject = $subject ;
 $msg = 'my html and php code that format the mail';
$body= preg_replace('/\[\]/','',$msg);
 $mail->msgHTML($body);
 $mail->msgHTML($message)
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
   echo "Message sent!";
 }
```

*Problem Arrises when only text is mailed is ok But html content is Not mailed using Phpmailer library.

*in this code i have send text its send with no error but problem in sending html

```
$msg = 'my html and php code that format the mail';
$body= preg_replace('/\[\]/','',$msg);
$mail->msgHTML($body);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    $data='<table border=1px solid>'.'<tr>'.'<td>'.'EMPLOYEE NAME'.'<td>'.'TO DATE'.'</td>'.'<td>'.'FROM DATE'.'</td>'.'<td>'.'LEAVETYPE'.'</td>'.'<td>'.'REASON'.'</td>.';

You Write Html Tags In Adding Way.

if you have any doubt ask me.


my Full code is

    $mail->MsgHTML("$data");

include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

$pa="SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_ID FROM ORGCHART";
$pa2=odbc_exec($conn,$pa);
while(odbc_fetch_row($pa2))
{
    $parentid=odbc_result($pa2,"PARENT_ID");

    $c=better_odbc_num_rows($conn,$parent);
    $leave2=odbc_exec($conn,$parent);
    $lv='';
    $cv='';
    $ov='';
    $hr="<table border=1px solid>"."<tr>"."<td>"."EMPLOYEE NAME"."<td>"."TO DATE"."</td>"."<td>"."FROM DATE"."</td>"."<td>"."LEAVETYPE"."</td>"."<td>"."REASON"."</td>.";
    while(odbc_fetch_row($leave2))
        {

            $todate=odbc_result($leave2,"TODATE");
            $todate=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($todate));
            $fromdate=odbc_result($leave2,"FROMDATE");
            $fromdate=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($fromdate));
            $lv.="<tr>"."<td>".odbc_result($leave2,"FIRSTNAME").
"</td>"."<td>".$todate."</td>"."<td>".$fromdate."</td>"."<td>".
    odbc_result($leave2,"LEAVETYPE")."</td>".
"<td>".odbc_result($leave2,"REASON")."</td>"."</tr>"."</br>";

        }
    if($c>0)
    {
        $ema="SELECT EMAIL FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID=$parentid";
        $ema=odbc_exec($conn,"$ema");
        $email=odbc_result($ema,"EMAIL");
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for hotMail
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';// secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587; // or 587
        $mail->STARTTLS = 1;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "";
        $mail->Password = "";
        $mail->SetFrom("");
        $mail->Subject = "eLeave";


    $mail->Body = "eLeave Tracking System";
            $mail->MsgHTML("$hr.$lv");
            $mail->AddAddress("");
            if(!$mail->Send()){
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else{
            echo "Message has been sent";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i have  not understand yr concept .pls elobrate

Comment: Hi - your answer is really unclear. I can't figure out what you're trying to say. Can you try to write a bit more explanation please?

Comment: iam append html tags using dot operator in php